# Why is this not outputting my selection?

Tags: jquery

The radio buttons have numeric values which will be added and displayed in the div: `sub-total-t`

## JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label').click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.option:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).data('number'))   
    });
    $('.sub-total-t').html('$' + total.toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

## HTML

```
<label><input type="radio" name="print" class="option" data-number="25" value="p10"/> Starter 500 </label>
<div id="sub-pricing">
<h3> Sub-Total </h3>
<div class="sub-total-t">$</div>
</div>
```

Why is this not displaying my value?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Your code works for me http://jsfiddle.net/9prqY/

Comment: It's not displaying the value of the radio button clicked. Example it should show what ever value I click and add the radio button. It does nothing. Checking firebug for error and dont see any

Comment: it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Pndh4/ unless you want to display `p10` insetd of `25`

Comment: Ok that is so weird it does work ... I have no idea why it wasn't working before.. No i don't it work as i intended it to -> Somehow it was glitching in my browser. Very strange..

Comment: @fabio: a tip for your next question http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wroking fine for me.Just using your code with little modification. See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kaidul/fGgJS/)